# I want to make it so when I click on the enemy, an ammo drop appears on the screen

Tags: monogame

Here is my code piece of code (I already have it so that when you click a ghost the ammo spawns, I just didn't include that because it was in a procedure.) My problem is with the RNG spawning of the ammo; it works fine at first and then after like 20 seconds it just does not spawn at all.

```
private void ammoSpawn()
    {
        ammoSpawner = rng.Next(1, 101);

        if (ammoSpawner > 50)
        {
            ammoTimer.Activate();

            if (ammoTimer.IsActive())
            {
                ammoRec.X = rng.Next(100, 1720);
                ammoRec.Y = rng.Next(100, 700);

                if (ammoTimer.IsFinished())
                {
                    ammoRec.X = -100;
                    ammoRec.Y = -100;

                    ammoTimer.ResetTimer(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show us the methods/functions of the `ammoTimer`? namely the `Activate()`, `IsActive()`, `IsFinished()` and `ResetTimer()`. It looks like there's a lot happening in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're reusing the same ammo object, and that the variables such as `ammoSpawner` and `ammoTimer` are public variables in game1.

I would recommend creating a seperate class for the ammo object. So all related code can remain in the ammo object, and that also makes it easier to create multiple items. (In case you're going to expand on that in the future)

An example of a create method in the Ammo Class:

```
int spawner = 0;
int timer = 0;
Texture2D ammoSprite = new Texture2D;
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

public void Ammo(Texture2D ammoSprite, _spawner, _timer) //this should be the constructor that creates the class
{
    spawner = _spawner;
    timer = _timer;
    rec.X = rng.Next(100, 1720);
    rec.Y = rng.Next(100, 700);
}
public void Update()
{
    //function where you put your update logic for the ammo object
}
public void Draw(Spritebatch spriteBatch)
{
    //function where you put your draw logic for the ammo object
    spriteBatch.Draw(ammoSprite, rect, Color.White);
}
```

then in the place where you'll use the ammo Class:

```
public Ammo ammo = null; //declared as a field on top of the page

private void ammoSpawn()
{
    Ammo ammo = new Ammo(); //creating an Ammo object, should be inside
}

public void Update()
{
    ammo.Update();
}

public void Draw()
{
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    ammo.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

Creating classes for objects are a core concept in C# to be able to reuse them. This also allows you to create multiple items/enemies that behave differently, but still keep the basic functions. I'd certainely recommend to learn about classes.